# Default Android Studio Navigation Drawer Icon

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I was having some problem when trying to change the default icon for navigation drawer in Android Studio.

So, I created a default navigation drawer activity.
[image]

The code are then auto generated for me. After trying to play around the code, I found out that the place to change the icon was under menu folder, activity_main_drawer.xml.

The code as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Then, I went to ic_menu_camera.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,12m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M9,2L7.17,4H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3.17L15,2H9zm3,15c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5z" />
</vector>
```

I realized that the icon was generated using the vector. Was thinking if there is another way to change the icon to take in my JPEG? Because after I changed the `android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"` into my JPEG under drawable folder also, the image just don't show up but a grey box. I even used an .ico but it does not work.

I think it's not necessary to provide all the codes because those are auto generated when you select the navigation drawer activity from Android Studio. For simplicity purpose, I just pasted out the part where you change the icon.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT

[image]

And my svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="90.000000pt" height="82.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 90.000000 82.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,82.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These images are a special kind - vectors or SVGs. You can import your own SVG by `right-clicking->new->vector asset` and choosing your own SVG.

You can download many icons on different sites, like [this one](https://design.google.com/icons/).

If you want your own custom ones, just export them from Illustrator as SVGs and import them in this way.

Comment: I see I see but I used online converter to convert my JPEG to SVG and then import into my Android Studio project, I realized that the format is kinda different from the default icons one. Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot speak for your particular case, since I don't see the image, and don't know how good that online converter is. I'd recommend that you do not use the converter (can't be better than originally exporting the image as SVG). Ask your designer to export it as SVG or search the web for a similar one that works for you.

Comment: I have updated the question. Do you mind to take a look?

Comment: Tried it on my machine, downloaded [this](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_send) icon, tried importing and it worked. Hm, can you try the whole process again?

Comment: Is it because I am trying to import my own converted svg file and that's why?

Comment: Probably. I am telling you, I have absolutely no idea how well the online converter converts the file (apparently not very well). Why don't you simply use the `send` icon from the link I provided, it's the official one to use :)

Comment: I see I see. Thanks a lot! But do you have any idea how to change the background color of navigation drawer item to white? because the default one was abit greyish and I am not able to find which part is doing the color.

Comment: Not a problem! :) I'm guessing it's this line in the drawable file `android:fillColor="#ffffff"`.

Comment: hey sorry one more question, do you know that before the 'Communication' there is a line separator. Because I looked all over the code and I can't simply find where is the part that added the line.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but I assume it's this. Find the xml where those items are (if you used a template for nav drawer, it is in menu folder I think) and remove a <group> tag and place all items in the same group. Two groups with different ids will have the line between them.

Comment: I was on my phone and couldn't see very clearly. Just remove these lines `<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>` and migrate the two items in the group above.